# How to convert, resize and center image with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm unable to center a converted *.png file with ImageMagick's gravity option. Gravity seems to have no effect in the following command. On the contrary it erases everything and the output becomes white page.

```
convert puma1.png -compress jpeg \
                  -resize 1755x2475 \
                  -units PixelsPerInch \
                  -density 150x150 \
                  -page A3 \
                  -gravity center puma1.pdf
```

ImageMagick version is 6.8.6-9 2014-03-06 Q16.

Comment: Can you post the `puma1.png` file please? BTW that command doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Closely related: "How to mount a .jpg centered into a .pdf (using defined page size and borders)?" http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43946

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `extent` instead like this:

```
$ convert puma1.png -gravity center \
    -background white \
    -compress jpeg \
    -extent 1755x2475 puma1.pdf
```

#### Example

Your gravatar.

[image: ss #1]

And the resulting PDF file.

```
$ convert 453f11e81477e1e0334962ee262b3bcd.png -gravity center \
    -background white \
    -extent 500x500 \
    -compress jpeg 453f11e81477e1e0334962ee262b3bcd.pdf
```

[image: ss #2]

#### References

- [Use ImageMagick to place an image inside a larger canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787356/use-imagemagick-to-place-an-image-inside-a-larger-canvas)

Comment: That... looks UGLY!

Comment: That's the switches.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. The original command with the new options is: `convert puma1.png -gravity center -background white -compress jpeg -resize 1755x2475 -extent 1755x2475 -units PixelsPerInch -density 150x150 puma1.pdf` It seems the option `-page A3` kills the output. In case I use it, I still get the blanc page at an output. What about `-resize` and `-extent`. Are they mutually exclusive?